# Difference in validation accuracy in transfer learning with tensorflow for poets and Keras custom code

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have trained a CNN using "Tensorflow for poets", having 90 percentage accuracy with a custom dataset. However when I am training the same dataset with same architecture for transfer learning with Keras with transfer learning backend, I am having the validation accuracy below 30 percentage. I am fairly new in machine learning, and I am guessing something is wrong with my code.

I am sharing my code below.

```
#importing assets
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.layers import Dense,GlobalAveragePooling2D,Flatten,Dropout
from keras.applications import MobileNet
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.mobilenet import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.models import load_model


#split dataset, defining params
train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
                            zoom_range=0.2,
            rotation_range=20,
            width_shift_range=0.25,
            height_shift_range=0.25,
            horizontal_flip=True,
            vertical_flip=True,
                            validation_split=0.2)
#train images
train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/home/khalder/cnn4/Train     Data',
                                             target_size=(224,224),
                                             color_mode='rgb',
                                             batch_size=100,
                                             class_mode='categorical',
                                             shuffle=True,
                                             subset='training')


validation_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/home/khalder/cnn4/Train Data',
                                             target_size=(224,224),
                                             color_mode='rgb',
                                             batch_size=100,
                                             class_mode='categorical',
                                             shuffle=True,
                                             subset='validation')


base_model=MobileNet(weights='imagenet',include_top=False,input_shape=(224, 224, 3)) #imports the mobilenet model and discards the last 1000 neuron layer.

x=base_model.output

x=Flatten()(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)

x=Dense(256,activation='relu')(x) #dense layer 2
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
x=Dense(256,activation='relu')(x) #dense layer 2

preds=Dense(90,activation='softmax')(x) #final layer with softmax activation
model=Model(inputs=base_model.input,outputs=preds)

print(len(model.layers))

for layer in model.layers:
layer.trainable=False

for layer in model.layers[80:]:
layer.trainable = True

model.compile(optimizer='Adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
# Adam optimizer
# loss function will be categorical cross entropy
# evaluation metric will be accuracy

step_size_train=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
filepath="weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.2f}.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=5, save_best_only=True, period=5)
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]


model.fit_generator( train_generator,
                 steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples // 100,
                 validation_data = validation_generator, 
                 validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // 100,
         callbacks=callbacks_list,
                 epochs = 5000)

model.save('train10class2.h5')
```

Answer (score 0):

In [tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/MobileNetV2) and [tf.keras.applications.MobileNet](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/MobileNet) documentation of `Tensorflow`, it has been mentioned:

**Caution: Be sure to properly pre-process your inputs to the application. Please see applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input for an example.**

In your case, instead of passing both `preprocess_input` and other `Data Augmentations` as arguments for `ImageDataGenerator`, pass only `preprocess_input` and it gives 25 to 30% more accuracy (I've tested at my end).

So, replacing the below code:

```
train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
                            zoom_range=0.2,
            rotation_range=20,
            width_shift_range=0.25,
            height_shift_range=0.25,
            horizontal_flip=True,
            vertical_flip=True,
                            validation_split=0.2)
```

with the just `preprocess_input` as shown below,

```
train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
```

**should resolve your issue**.

Also, you have instantiated `ImageDataGenerator` only once and have used that object for Validation, `validation_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory`.

Many books (including the one written by Father of `Keras`, `Francois Chollet`) has instantiated the `ImageDataGenerator` Class separately for `Training` and `Validation`.

So, you can use

```
train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
val_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory
validation_generator=val_datagen.flow_from_directory
```